# How do I pass a variable to inline javascript using EJS templating engine?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, ejs

I've created a html list of buttons/text from an array called items in an .EJS template. How do I pass the specific item's id (item.id) to the button's function so I can send the right data to my api? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Menu</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function print(id) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.example.com/api/1/print",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "item_id": id
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
          }
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <ul>
        <% for(item of items) { %>
          <li>
            <button onclick="print(item.id)">PRINT</button>
            <%= item.name %> - <%= item.id %>
          </li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<button onclick="print('<%= item.id %>')">PRINT</button>
```

is how you would do it in every templating language I have used. After looking at the docs, it appears EJS is the same

Comment: what isn't working about it? what is the output markup with the code I posted?

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: mxYbGAuc9p is not defined" because the html compiles to <button onclick="print(mxYbGAuc9p)">PRINT</button>

Comment: What is the generated HTML? Please run the code the way I originally posted, and post the resulting HTML. We need to look at what is being produced by EJS. Add it as an edit to your original question.

Comment: HTML: https://gist.github.com/sapanbhuta/53036968ab3612261d5f  EJS: https://gist.github.com/sapanbhuta/ce79b4ffdaded3b1c442

Comment: is that the id? if so you need additional quotes. (I was assuming id was an integer, my bad). see my update

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="print('<%= item.id %>')">PRINT</button>
```

wrap your variable up with the template tags, within a single quotes